# How fast would strangelets travel in space?

Tags: space, space-travel, stars, supernova, strange-matter

At what speed would strange matter travel in space after being ejected from a neutron star merger? I have searched around online but I have not found an answer.

Comment: As written this seems like more of an astronomy question about existing real world phenomena rather than building a fictional world.

Comment: Look up the speeds of the other particles ejected by the sun. Pretty sure neutrinos move just a smidgen below lightspeed. The proton and electron cosmic rays should move slower cause they're bigger. But I expect that means 90% lightspeed compared to 99.999475%. So anything like this should move close to lightspeed.

Answer (score 2):

**> 0.97 C**

As told [here](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/faster-than-light-neutron-star-merger-shot-out-a-jet-with-seemingly-impossible-speed/),

> The dramatic neutron-star merger that astronomers spotted last year
> generated a jet of material that seemed to move at four times the
> speed of light, a new study reports.
>
> “Seemed” is the operative word here. So, the superluminal motion was
> an illusion.
>
> Adam Deller, of the Swinburne University of Technology in Australia,
> said in a statement from the National Radio Astronomy Observatory
> (NRAO).
>
> “But to match our observations, the material in the jet also has to be
> blasting outwards at over 97 percent of the speed of light,” he added.

So the speed may be > 0.97 C.